# Python : `variables` in a POST body should be provided as an object, not a recursively JSON-encoded string

Tags: python, json, object, post

I'm using the following method to insert a variable into a POST request body :

`def get_variables(date): return '{{"date":"{0}","timezone":"Europe"}}'.format(date)`

The query is the following :

`query Exchange($date: String!, $timezone: String) { getIntervals(date: $date, timezone: $timezone) { date intervals { start end description type code } } }`

I get this error message when executing `get_variable`

`variables in a POST body should be provided as an object, not a recursively JSON-encoded string.`

Any idea for how turn it into a JSON object in python please ?

Comment: Don't enclose it in quotes.

Comment: When not inclosing in quote `return {{"date": "{0}", "timezone": "Europe"}}.format(date)`
I have `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode this data as a string, return a regular dictionary instead:

```
def get_variables(date):
    return {"date": str(date), "timezone": "Europe"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update : Resolved.

I've used `json.loads()` function to do the deserialization – the act of converting a string to an object. --> `def get_variables(date): return json.loads('{{"date": "{0}", "timezone": "Europe"}}'.format(date))`

Thank you all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).